# Java PriorityQueue and Comparable interface

Tags: java, data-structures, priority-queue, comparable

Hi there folks

I've been looking at how to implement and use Java PriorityQueue.
The queue I need has to be able to compare priority of two different type of objects.
I found and read this [PriorityQueue](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/priorityqueue.shtml) article, but there is no mention if it's possible to compare two different type of objects.

Do you know if it's possible?

Thanks
Gunnlaugur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Object` is the most general class and is superclass of everything, you may implement your own `Comparator <Object>`, declare your queue as `PriorityQueue <Object>` and pass your comparator to queue's constructor.

Comment: Okay, so I could then just have my two different classes implement `code`Comparator<Object>`code`. and use something like `code`compare(Object o1, Object o2)`code` and then my implementation of the compare function.

Comment: If you use your own `Comparator <Object>`, that will compare objects by it's own rules, then your classes may or may not implement `Comparatable <Object>` - for queue, that has no difference, comparation will totally be delivered to your brand new comparator.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I totally understand your answer.

Comment: If you will create a `PriorityQueue` via `new PriorityQueue(int, Comparator)`, then comparison will be done by your `Comparator`, that you've passed to a queue constructor, and queue will not worry about object type - as long, as you `Comparator` is able to handle it. But if you will use other `PriorityQueue` constructor, which doesn't requires a `Comparator`, then elements will be sorted according to their _natural ordering_ - via `compareTo` method in the `Comparable` interface. In this case, they **MUST** implement `Comparable`, or your queue will throw a `ClassCastException` upon `add`.

Answer (score 2):

According to Java 1.6's API, [you can provide a `Comparator` to the `PriorityQueue` constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue%28int,%20java.util.Comparator%29). Also, you can let the queue objects' classes implement the [`Comparable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface, which defines a `compareTo` method that is invoked to compare the objects.